# How to ping all the ip in LAN using Terminal?

Tags: command-line, ping

I am trying to ping all the systems available in the local area network using terminal command.

Can any one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install an application called `nmap`.

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Then you can check your entire network for all connected IP addresses by typing in the following:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24
```

The above command will scan all IP addresses starting at `192.168.1.1` through `192.168.1.254` and show you all IPs that responded.

You can scan other IP address ranges like `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.254` by typing in the following:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/23
```

A typical scan might return something like the following:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ nmap -sP 10.0.0.1/24

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-24 00:20 MST
Nmap scan report for Linksys03773 (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00078s latency).
Nmap scan report for terrance-ubuntu (10.0.0.100)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
Nmap scan report for android (10.0.0.148)
Host is up (0.099s latency).
Nmap scan report for PC (10.0.0.149)
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.150
Host is up (0.0016s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.165
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.169
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.179
Host is up (0.014s latency).
Nmap scan report for android (10.0.0.181)
Host is up (0.093s latency).
Nmap scan report for android (10.0.0.188)
Host is up (0.043s latency).
Nmap scan report for android (10.0.0.196)
Host is up (0.014s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.253
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (12 hosts up) scanned in 4.46 seconds
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**fping** is another command to ping all ip in LAN.

```
fping -a -r 0 -g 192.168.9.0/24

192.168.9.48
192.168.9.71
192.168.9.72
192.168.9.73
192.168.9.75
192.168.9.79
192.168.9.81
192.168.9.82
ICMP Redirect from 192.168.9.4 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.168.9.83
192.168.9.84
192.168.9.85
192.168.9.87
192.168.9.88
192.168.9.90
192.168.9.92
192.168.9.104
192.168.9.106
192.168.9.108
192.168.9.109
192.168.9.116
192.168.9.117
ICMP Host Unreachable from 192.168.9.214 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.168.9.1
192.168.9.120
ICMP Host Unreachable from 192.168.9.214 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.168.9.2
```

`-a` Show systems that are alive.

`-r` n Retry limit (default 3). This is the number of times an attempt at
            pinging a target will be made, not including the first try.

`-g` addr/mask
            Generate a target list from a supplied IP netmask, or a starting
            and ending IP.  Specify the netmask or start/end in the targets
            portion of the command line. If a network with netmask is given,
            the network and broadcast addresses will be excluded.

To scan range of IP addresses from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.9 just run:

```
sudo fping -s -g 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.9 -r 1
```

That will output:

```
192.168.0.1 is alive
192.168.0.7 is alive
192.168.0.2 is unreachable
192.168.0.3 is unreachable
192.168.0.4 is unreachable
192.168.0.5 is unreachable
192.168.0.6 is unreachable
192.168.0.8 is unreachable
192.168.0.9 is unreachable

9 targets
2 alive
7 unreachable
0 unknown addresses

14 timeouts (waiting for response)
16 ICMP Echos sent
2 ICMP Echo Replies received
0 other ICMP received

0.05 ms (min round trip time)
0.44 ms (avg round trip time)
0.84 ms (max round trip time)
2.183 sec (elapsed real time)
```

[Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/fping.8.html) is the ubuntu manual to use fping with different options.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways:

- Use `nmap` to scan entire local subnets in only one command. For
  example: `nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24`
- Use `arp-scan`, it sends ARP packets to hosts on the local network
  and displays any responses that are received. By default, it's not
  installed. So install it by the command `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`.

Once it's accomplished. Launch this command to scan entire local network on the specified interface (For example, your network interface is named `eth0`):

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

or give a specific subnet:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 192.168.0.1/24
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ping all the hosts on a LAN is with IPv6:

```
ping6 -nc2 ff02::1%eth0
```

The `-n` flag means no reverse DNS will be performed. Without that it would be slowed down by trying to perform reverse DNS on link-local addresses, which is not going to work anyway.

The `-c2` flag means it will send only two pings before terminating.

The address `ff02::1` is an anycast address targeting all hosts on the link.

Finally `%eth0` is the notation appended to link-local IPv6 addresses in order to indicate which interface to be using. Usually this will be `eth0` or `wlan0`.

You can do the same with IPv4, but it involves an additional step to look up the broadcast address for the segment.

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:a4:08:97  
          inet addr:172.20.124.289  Bcast:172.20.124.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fea4:897/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92446832 errors:0 dropped:669 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52031936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:97720895471 (97.7 GB)  TX bytes:18694928767 (18.6 GB)
$ ping -bnc2 172.20.124.255
```

Here I first used `ifconfig` to see what the IP address of `eth0` is and then I ping it. Additionally I need the `-b` flag to tell `ping` that I really do want to ping a broadcast address.